# Getting notified about available NuGet packages updates

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

Visual Studio allows me to see what updates are available for referenced NuGet packages. It allows me as well to update all versions simultaneously .

Yet I cannot find similar functionality for `dotnet` CLI.

Is it possible to get the list of updates and/or update everything with single command?

Answer (score 1):

From the [ASP.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on):

> From the Package Manager Console (PMC), you can enter the `Update-Package` command, which will update all packages.

Edit: It wasn't asked, but in case you'd like the GUI version, this can be found under `Project -> Manage NuGet Packages...`

Comment: It's how to update them, but what if I need to see the history line of new versions released after the one my project references.

Comment: See if `Get-Package -updates` does what your looking for. According to the docs, it lists all available NuGet package updates for the packages used in your project.